# Proof involving chords of a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

> In a circumference with center $O$, three chords $\overline{AB},\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{CB}$ such that the last two intersect in $E$. Show that $AE·AD+BE·BC=AB^2 $.
>   **Added**: $O\in\overline{AB}$.

Hi, I have been trying to solve this problem with the power of a point with respect to a circumference and with pythagoras, but it seems that I'm going nowhere:

$2(AB)^2=AD^2+BD^2+BC^2+AC^2$

I hope you could give me a hint. Thanks

Edit: Taking into account what Blue mentioned: [image]

Comment: Do you know that $O$ is on $\overline{AB}$?

Comment: The problem does not state it. But I guess yes

Comment: If $O$ were not on $AB$ the statement would not be true. Indeed, we could move both $A$ and $B$ close to the top of the picture, thus making $AB$ very short, and at the same time move all of $C$, $E$ and $D$ close to the bottom of the picture, thus making all of $AE$, $AD$, $BE$, and $BC$ long, so the left-hand side would be much larger than the right-hand side.

Comment: Drop a perpendicular from $E$ to point $P$ on $AB$. Also, add segments $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$, noting the right angles at $C$ and $D$. Find two pairs of similar triangles, and use some appropriate proportions.

Comment: The proportions you've derived from my hint are correct. Cross-multiply to turn them into product relations ... $$BE\cdot BC = AB \cdot PB \qquad AE\cdot AD = AB \cdot AP$$ ... and notice that the left-hand sides of these are on the left-hand side of the target relation; so ... ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't see that when I factor out $AB$ I get $(PB+PA)=AB$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on a good track. You found that
$$2 \cdot AB^2 = AD^2 + BD^2 + BC^2 + AC^2.$$
But you want something with $AD \cdot AE,$ not $AD^2,$ you don't want to see $BD^2,$
and so forth.
But notice that $AC^2 = AE^2 - CE^2$ and $BD^2 = BE^2 - DE^2,$
and also $AD = AE + DE$ and $BC = BE + CE.$
So this suggests you could put everything on the right-hand side in terms of 
$AE,$ $BE,$ $CE,$ and $DE.$

So the hint is, do that, then see if you can put the pieces back together to make
$2 \cdot AD \cdot AE + 2 \cdot BC \cdot BE.$ If you get that far,
you can easily complete the proof.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow and will tell you if I succeeded. Thanks for the hint. It looks as though it'll work.

Comment: $$2AB^2=AD^2+BE^2-DE^2+BC^2+AE^2-CE^2$$
$$=AD^2+BC^2+(AE+DE)(AE-DE)+(BE+CE)(BE-CE)$$
$$AD(AD+AE-DE)+BC(BC+BE-CE) = AD(2AE)+BC(2BE). \text{ QED.}$$

Cheers David